# Null значения в ключах и ссылки из них, MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возможно ли каким-то образом сделать столбец содержащий NULL значения определить ключем и потом сделать, чтобы он ссылался на другую таблицу? (На первом скрине столбец, который нужно, чтобы ссылался на ID в таблице на втором скрине)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если коротко - то "нет" два раза.

Comment: @Akina Хорошо, спасибо)

Comment: Foreign key или Primary key+Foreign key?

Comment: @Anatoly мне только Foreign Key нужен, чтобы ссылку организовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Отсутствие значения в колонке, от которой идет ссылка вполне допустимо. Просто создайте Foreign key указав ее.

Главное чтобы все непустые значения присутствовали в таблице с другой стороны ключа. Как создавать ключ см например [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15)